# Azure Devops repositories viewing

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-repos

I have a lot of project on Azure DevOps. And I want to view my repository in other projects from within my current project. Is it possible to see repositories from different projects within the same project in Azure Devops?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You are limited just to repositories within your project. If this is your need, please consider moving all repos into one project.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround: create a wiki page with links to the various repos in other projects. Keep in mind projects are secured separately so users might not be able to access repos in other projects.